# Why should not reference the library directly from the Android SDK directory?

Tags: android

I am new to Android app development.

I read the note on step 3 of Add Google Play Services to Your Project in this [link](http://developer.android.com/google/play-services/setup.html).

Why should we reference a copy of library but not directly from the Android SDK directory?

Is there any software engineering principle behind?

Comment: Ask to `Google` Developers ..

Comment: Because if you update the library via the SDK manager, you have no control of the version used for your projects which can lead to incompatibilities. Still, this is kinda off-topic here.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about Google Play Service Library Dependencies

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use it directly from the Android SDK directory. But i think, Google recommends to copy library just for compatibility. If you are using link, so after update to new version of SDK (and  Google Play Services) your code may not working any more (if they change something in api, for example).